# Git submodule: manually change sha1

Tags: git, git-submodules

Simple thing, I have a project with a submodule. At some point a change in the submodule was not pushed, but the superproject was pushed.

Now, the superproject's sha-1 ref to the submodule points to an unexisting commit on the server side, so git cannot update the submodule (`error: no such remote ref 8ba0033813718939726d7e9429bf3eabcc52034d`)

I simply want to set the sha-1 to some other value -- but since the update fails, I cannot use `git checkout ...` in the submodule (which is the accepted solution for every question that looks like that on SO).

I tried to explore .git/modules/... but I cannot find where it is stored.

If you want more info about the project's structure, you can find the project [here](https://gitlab-ce.iut.u-bordeaux.fr/icanet/iut-info) and the submodule [here](https://github.com/CLOVIS-AI/latex-template).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though `git checkout master` doesn't work in the submodule, I managed to get `git checkout [commit hash]` to work -- and it solves the problem.